# print from users input linked list of struct

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am required to have a list of structs of sentence nodes that point to a struct of word nodes.  I am trying to print the user's input.

I have a program that runs properly when I manually give it the input (see test section of the code). It does not, however, work when I use my input1() function.

I've tried debugging it, but I can't seem to find the problem.
I removed all printf lines that I used to debug. I also removed all the irrelevant code.

I am looking to know how to fix it and what is wrong so I can run it with no problems.

What I learned from debugging it is that (only when using input1() and not in the test) the head is overwritten every time and all the nodes as well.
I also tried using a double pointer instead of returning para but that didn't help.

any help will be appreciated,

thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct word
{
    char * ch;//poiter to char
}
W;
typedef struct sentence
{
    W * currentWord;//pointer to a word
    int lineNumber;// holds the line number
    int numbersOfWords;//holds the number of words
    struct sentence* link;
}
sent;
typedef struct list
{
    sent* head;
    int count;
}
LISTS;

LISTS* createList()
{
    LISTS* list;
    list= (LISTS*) malloc (sizeof (LISTS));
    if (list)
    {
        list-> head = NULL;
        list-> count = 0;
    }
    return list;
} // createList
void printList(LISTS*  list)
{
    sent *temp = list -> head;

    //iterate the entire linked list and print the data
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", temp->currentWord->ch);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
//    printf("NULL\n");
}
void insertSentList (LISTS* list, W* itemPtr)
{
    sent* newPtr; //new node
      if (!(newPtr = (sent * ) malloc(sizeof(sent)))){
        printf(" Memory can not be allocated.");
        return;
    }
    newPtr->currentWord = itemPtr;
    newPtr->link = NULL;
    if(list->head == NULL)
    {
        list->head = newPtr;
    }else{
    sent* current = list->head;
    while(current->link != NULL){
        current = current->link;
        }
    current -> link = newPtr;
        }
    (list->count)++;
    return;
}  // insertList
LISTS * input1(LISTS *para)
{
    char * line;
    line = (char * ) malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
    line[0] = '\0';

    while (line[0] != '\n')
    {
      W word;
            word.ch = (char * ) malloc(100);
      printf(" Please input a line : ");
      fgets(line, 1000, stdin);
      if(line[0] != '\n'){
        strcpy(word.ch, line);
                insertSentList(para,&word);
            }
    }
    free(line);
    return para;
}
int main()
{
    ///////////////////test////////////////
  LISTS* list = createList();
    
  W word;
  word.ch= "word0 ";
  W word1;
  word1.ch= "word1 ";
  W word2;
  word2.ch= "word2";

  insertSentList(list,&word);
  insertSentList(list,&word1);
  insertSentList(list,&word2);
    insertSentList(list,&word);
  insertSentList(list,&word1);
  insertSentList(list,&word2);

  printList(list);
    ///////////////////test////////////////

  LISTS *para = createList();
  para= input1(para);
  printList(para);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `insertSentList(para,&word);` Here `word` is a local variable in the `while` loop inside `input1`. It ends life after each iteration and gets rewritten at the next one, but `insertSentList` saves a pointer to it into the list, which is no longer valid by the time `printList` is called.

Comment: i updated the code so that it copies what word points to in insert into a variable and used that variable instead. unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: `W itemPtr = *word;` This make a copy into another local variable, this time in `insertSentList`, which has the same problem as before. (Besides, you are not even using the copy after making it.)

Comment: sorry I didn't  think it through correctly! But how I'm I supposed to take in users input without changing what word is? if I declare word outside the while loop that wont change the fact that it's rewritten. Do you have any suggestions? @dxiv

Comment: also if i make it so that i pass the function the actual word instead of a pointer it will start printing gibberish .

Comment: Too long for a comment, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem with the posted code is that "ownership" of the `sent` and `W` objects in a list is not well defined. For example `word.ch= "word0 ";` in `main` sets the `ch` pointer pointing to a string literal (which it does not own), but `word.ch = malloc(100);` in `input1` points it to dynamically allocated memory (which it should own, and remember to `free` later). Because of this, memory allocations cannot be tracked reliably and, even in the cases where things appear to "work", there are multiple memory leaks. It also breaks when the inserted objects are local variables that do not live for the entire lifetime of the list object.

The simplest (if not necessarily the best or most efficient) solution would be to dynamically allocate all objects that go into the list, make the list own them all, and add a function to cleanup once done. To that end `insertSentList` could be modified as follows.

```
void insertSentList (LISTS* list, W* itemPtr)
{
    sent* newPtr; //new node
      if (!(newPtr = malloc(sizeof(sent)))){
        printf(" Memory can not be allocated.\n");
        return;
    }
    W *newItem = malloc(sizeof(W));    // <-- make a deep copy of the `itemPtr` argument
    newItem->ch = strdup(itemPtr->ch); //     including a copy of the string itself
    newPtr->currentWord = newItem;     // <-- save the copy in the list, not the argument
    newPtr->link = NULL;
    if(list->head == NULL)
    {
      list->head = newPtr;
    }else{
      sent* current = list->head;
      while(current->link != NULL){
        current = current->link;
      }
      current->link = newPtr;
    }
    list->count++;
}  // insertList
```

For proper cleanup and to avoid memory leaks, the following `freeList` should be called for each list pointer returned by `createList` and filled by `insertSentList`.

```
void freeList(LISTS *list)
{
    sent *temp = list->head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
      sent *next = temp->link;
      free(temp->currentWord->ch);
      free(temp->currentWord);
      free(temp);
      temp = next;
    }
    free(list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really didn't understand ownership that well, I have a lot to work on when it comes to understanding of memory. Your explanation is very clear. Thank you very much, I highly appreciated your answer.

Comment: @hitomilayla At the basic level, managing "ownership" means deciding who is responsible for each acquired resource. When you write a `malloc` call, think at when that memory will no longer be needed, and which code will be responsible to `free` it. Same for `fopen` / `fclose`, `strdup` / `free` etc.